# How to pernamently disable Caps Lock in Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, capslock

I am never using Caps Lock, it is pressed only by mistake. How can I fully disable it? Preferably during system start, so login menu will be also affected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setxkbmap -option caps:none` disables Caps Lock. To make it pernament it is necessary to add this command to autostart.

To do this in Lubuntu go to start menu, select "Preferences", run "Default Applications for LXSession". Then go to tab "Autostart" and add this command using "Manual autostarted application".

It disables Caps Lock on login, unfortunately it is not disabling Caps Lock on entering username and password on logging in.

Answer based on http://www.howtogeek.com/194705/how-to-disable-or-reassign-the-caps-lock-key-on-any-operating-system/

Comment: Maybe would be useful to add how to do it from the command line. That way it could be automated with a script.

Answer (score 2):

Get a screwdriver, lever it under the caps lock key. With
extreme prejudice, ping it off.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to repurpose it for other keyboard shortcuts.